# Is it possible to install gnome shell extension in unity?

Tags: gnome-shell-extension

I want an applet [netctl-gnome](https://github.com/surfatwork/netctlgnome), that is available for gnome shell as extension, to use on unity, is there anyway to install it?

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: It looks like the closest you'll get to what you're asking is this: http://www.howtogeek.com/112620/how-to-install-use-gnome-shell-on-ubuntu/?PageSpeed=noscript

Comment: @ColonelTrogdor it shows how to install gnome-shell on Ubuntu, it does not help to use gnome extension or applet on ubuntu, not even close ;)

Comment: Which is why I said "closest" instead of "close", I think bodhi.zazen is right that it's not possible to do what you're asking.  Gnome extensions tend not to work on Unity, as explained at https://askubuntu.com/questions/85915/are-gnome-shell-extensions-compatible-with-unity if you install the gnome shell, you'll be able to use the extension.  Unfortunately, I think my previous comment is the closest you'll get.  And you should still be able to access the Unity GUI through the login screen if that is what you'd prefer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is "impossible" to solve (That is: without digging into the code and rewriting the plugin for Unity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible without porting the entire applet.

Gnome and Unity shell work very differently and share no code.
The consequence: A Gnome Shell applet cannot run on Unity or vice versa.

Comment: Better then closing, Sorry! (And upvoted)

Comment: I was exploring new Ubuntu 18.10 features including GS Connect a gnome-shell extension that allows controlling android phones from Ubuntu. I was disappointed to learn from your answer (that I upvoted ;)) it won't work in Unity. However like many things in he Linux world GS Connect is based upon a different app. The full blown apt is called KDE Connect (which **might** to have nothing to do with KDE). So I'll be installing KDE Connect in Unity 7.4 (Ubuntu 16.04) first and Unity 7.5 later (Ubuntu 18.04). To make a long comment short: ***A Unity version may exist for the gnome-shell applet.***